# F# Two Arrays - First Array Product Filtered By Index On Second Array

Tags: arrays, indexing, filter, f#

I have three arrays - **first** is a float array, **second** is a string array, and **fltr** is a string array. I need to generate a product of the elements in the first array filtered by whether the matching index in the second array contains all the characters in the elements of the filter array:

```
module SOQN = 

   open System

   let first   = [| 2.00;   3.00;   5.00;   7.00;   11.00 |]
   let second  = [| "ABCD"; "ABCE"; "ABDE"; "ACDE"; "BCDE" |]
   let fltr    = [| "AC";   "BD";   "CE" |]

   let result =
      first
      |> Array.filter second // filter for elements containing characters in second array
      |> Seq.reduce (fun x y -> x * y)

   // Expected Result: let result = [| 42.00; 110.00; 231.00 |]
```

How do I generate the array of products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
let first   = [| 2.00;   3.00;   5.00;   7.00;   11.00 |]
let second  = [| "ABCD"; "ABCE"; "ABDE"; "ACDE"; "BCDE" |]
let fltr    = "AC"

Array.zip first second
|> Array.filter (fun (_, s) ->
    Seq.forall (fun c -> s.Contains (string c)) fltr)
|> Array.map fst
|> Array.reduce (*)
```

Comment: What if **filtr** is also an array of two character strings?

Comment: It would still work, because `string[]` is also a `seq` (IEnumerable in C#)

Comment: How would I generate the array of products?

Comment: For beginner question, I suggest asking on #beginner channel of fsharp slack. http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/

But for the above question, I think you could use `Array.map` on fltr array

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet (though not idiomatic) provides the complete answer I was seeking and includes @xuanduc987 solution:

```
module SOANS = 

open System

let first   = [| 2.00;   3.00;   5.00;   7.00;   11.00 |]
let second  = [| "ABCD"; "ABCE"; "ABDE"; "ACDE"; "BCDE" |]
let fltr    = [| "AC";   "BD";   "CE" |]

let filterProduct (first:float[]) (second:string[]) (fltr:string) = 
    Array.zip first second
    |> Array.filter (fun (_, s) ->
        Seq.forall (fun c -> s.Contains (string c)) fltr)
    |> Array.map fst
    |> Array.reduce (*)

let third = 
    [for i in [0..fltr.Length - 1] do
        yield (filterProduct first second fltr.[i])]
    |> List.toArray

printfn "Third: %A" third

// Expected Result: Third: [| 42.0; 110.0; 231.0 |]
// Actual Result    Third: [| 42.0; 110.0; 231.0 |]
```